# parsing a iCal RRULE (from RFC 5545)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, icalendar, recurrence

I'm looking for a solution to parsing recurring event with ruby (on rails).

I'd like to parse RRULE part of an appointment to know if it's occurs between 2 date.

For exemple, I have this rule :

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=6;BYMONTH=11;
```

I like to know when it occur this year:

```
scheduler.parse_ical('DTSTART:20111216T090000Z;RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=6;BYMONTH=11;')
scheduler.occurrences(Time.now, Time.now + 2.years)
=> return : 2012-11-06 09:00:00, 2013-11-06 09:00:00
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by myself :-)

I'd fork ice_cube library and commit some patch to have this functionality : https://github.com/digITpro/ice_cube